# поиск по подмассиву

Tags: javascript

Хочу получить из исходного массива другой массив:

пример ввода:

```
[[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]
```

вывод должен быть такой: первое число - **возраст** должно быть больше **55**, а второе - **стаж работы** должен быть больше **7**.

```
["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]
```

Мой код вроде бы решает, но я готов выкинуть его в топку, решение никак не универсально, прошу помощи:

```js
var arr = [[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]];
var arr2 = [];

function openOrSenior(data){
  
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] > 55 && data[i][1] > 7) {
      arr2.push("Senior");
    } else {
      arr2.push("Open");
    }
   }
   return arr2;
  }
}

console.log(openOrSenior(arr));
```

1. Как избавиться от глобальных переменных?
2. Как проверять на массив универсально?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отображения одной коллекции элементов в другую используется [метод map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr = [
  [18, 20],
  [45, 2],
  [61, 12],
  [37, 6],
  [21, 21],
  [78, 9]
];
var arr2 = [];

function openOrSenior(data) {

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {

    return data.map(el => el[0] > 55 && el[1] > 7 ? "Senior" : "Open");
  }
}
console.log(openOrSenior(arr));
```

Comment: хорош благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

1. у вас глобальная переменная только **arr2**. В JavaScript область видимости функциональная, так что вам достаточно перенести объявление переменной внутрь функции.
2. Проверять на массив можно следующим образом:

> ```
> function isArray(someVar) {   
>     if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
>       return true    
>     } else {
>       return false
> }}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
function openOrSenior(data){
  function determineMembership(member){
    return (member[0] >= 55 && member[1] > 7) ? 'Senior' : 'Open';
  }
  return data.map(determineMembership);
}
```